# Solid state relay (optocoupled triac) is extraordinarily hot when on

Tags: solid-state-relay

I am using the following part: 3-32VDC input to 240VAC max 40A, [KD20C40AX](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/176719.pdf), that is connected to an Arduino Uno that drives a 5V control signal to the opto.  The application, (output/triac side), is simply turning on and off a water heater that is running at 240VAC nominal current draw of 18A.  The problem is that when the relay is in the on-state, drawing the 18A, the relay quickly rises to over 200degF in some places.  See the following photo, the orange color is the temperature measured on the side of the relay, in degreesF, and the reddish line is the current in Amps.[image]

What I would like to know is what about this configuration is abnormal?  Is the 5V input signal too low and resulting in a semi-on, high resistance state?  Any recommendations for a less dissipating option?

Comment: max 2V drop times 18A makes 36W you have to dissipate...

Comment: I went down the same thought path, but initially thought that 36W, max, was still a little low for how hot it was.  Maybe not.  Any ideas on an alternate to make this less costly?

Comment: Look at your soldering irons wattage and compare that to the 36W ... Either add proper heatsinking/airflow, live with it (I have no idea about the SOA of that device) or look for something with a lower drop (maybe based on low \$R_{DS(on)}\$ fets) or use some "real" relay (you are switching far below 1Hz anyways).

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  Was hoping you wouldn't say that...

Comment: Sometimes mechanical switching really is the only straightforward option.